# Idiom for spending too much time on a single topic?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, idiom-requests

Is there an idiom (or just an adjective) for spending too much time on a topic?  What about saying the same thing over and over again in different ways?

Example:
"We don't need to keep talking about this, I think everyone has already made their point and we keep going in circles."

Comment: You should give more details about “a single topic”, and add a sample sentence where the expression should be used.

Comment: How about "EL&U"?

Answer (score 2):

***harp on***

> to talk about (a subject) constantly or repeatedly in an annoying way, to dwell on or recur to a subject tiresomely or monotonously
>
> - She's always ***harping on*** the importance of a good diet. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harp%20on#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20harp%20on,importance%20of%20a%20good%20diet.))

This is the shortened version of the idiom ***to harp on the same string*** about which [the same dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/harp-on-verb-origin-history#:%7E:text=To%20harp%20on%20the%20same,happens%20to%20be%20within%20earshot.) explains

> ***To harp on the same string*** means to play the same note continuously. It's not a stretch to understand that the sound of the same note being continuously played, no matter the instrument, can have a nagging effect on whoever happens to be within earshot.